# How to make image of characters compatible with characters of a font?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, textview, spannablestring

As Bangla Complex font rendering is not supported, complex characters are shown broken (like ক্ষ is shown as ক+্‌+ষ ). So I'm replacing only those complex characters by the image in my TextView using SpannableStringBuilder with code:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(txt);
    Drawable bm = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.kuu); 
 setTextSize(25);
    bm.setBounds(0,0,15,(int)getTextSize()); 
............
ssb.setSpan( new ImageSpan( bm ), ofe, ofe+3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

All other characters come from a font i have attached to my TextView usig TypeFace, But the result is like:
[image]

Images don't align perfectly with characters from the font as View is growing in size. So, please help me to overcome this problem, I don't want to use the image for every character, tried many things with no luck, looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to restrict the View from growing vertically & allow it to be scrollable Horizontally. But I finally used image for each character (The no of images required was greatly reduced by using **Overlay** technique).